# How do I revert Object.defineProperty on Node to the original state after it was overridden?

Tags: javascript, dom, overriding

In my javascript (running in the browser) code a 3rd-party library has overridden the Node.childNodes getter/setter.

For the sake of example, let us say I have done it myself with the following code:

```
  Object.defineProperty(Node.prototype, 'childNodes', {

     get() {
      return "overridden!"
     },
     set(value) {
      //
     }

});
```

Now I want to select an element and get its child nodes.
(`document.querySelector('body').childNodes`)

If I have a freshly create iframe, can I use it to select node elements in the main window ?

My aim here is to be able to get the childNodes on an element after this property (`Node.prototype.childNodes`) has already been overridden.

**Note**

I realize having a 3rd party library that overrides DOM element functions is bad. But this is the given situation I am trying to solve.

Comment: If you want tag elements only, you can use the `children` property, unless the lib has overwritten that too?

Comment: I can't trust the property not to have been overridden, so I want to use my own original function.

Comment: I suspect you're going to be all out of luck here. The not-very-helpful answer is to not use badly behaved 3rd party libraries that think it's acceptable to redefine DOM methods/properties.

Comment: Hmm. Well, it's not the answer you're looking for, but I'd be *very* reticent before using anything that overwrote native properties and functionality. That's not cool.

Comment: I agree with you regarding that, but I am trying to find a solution in this given situation.

Comment: You could try `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` on the `Node.prototype` from an iframe - this is the standard approach for native objects, I don't know whether it would work for DOM objects as well

Comment: @Bergi not sure I understand your answer. How do I select and get the childNodes from my iframe ? (the element I want to select is outside the iframe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an iframe with an intact `Node.prototype.childNodes`, you should be able to do

```
Object.defineProperty(Node.prototype, "childNodes", 
  Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(iframe.contentWindow.Node.prototype, "childNodes")
);
```

to restore the getter/setter in your main window. After that, `document.body.childNodes` should work normally again.